# Pseudolatin en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola buenas estaba realizando un codigo donde dada una cadena en lenguaje natural, sin espacios duplicados tengo que convertirla al pseudo latín.
El pseudo latín consiste en agregar a cada palabra de mas de una letra, las letras "um" en caso de terminar el consonante, o en caso te terminar el vocal, se quita la última vocal y se le agrega "um".

Entrada: El pájaro campana canta hasta morir

Salida: Elum pájarum campanum cantum hastum morirum

Nose porque no me imprime la ultima palabra en latin:

Elum pájarum campanum cantum hastum

```
def TraducirPseudoLatin(cadena,consonantes,vocales,simbolos):
    cont = 0
    cant = 0
    latin = []

    for i in cadena: #longitud de la cadena
        cont += 1
    for n in range(cont):

        if cadena[n] in simbolos: #detectar si hay un simbolo

            if cadena[n-1] in consonantes: #encontrar consonantes para reemplazar
                cad1 = cadena[cant:n]
                ca1= cad1 + "um"
                latin.append(ca1)
                for j in cad1:
                    cant+=1
                cant+=1

            if cadena[n-1] in vocales: #encontrar vocales para reemplazar
                cad = cadena[cant:n-1]
                ca= cad + "um"
                latin.append(ca)
                for j in cad:
                    cant+=1
                cant+=2
               
    for i in latin:
        print (i, end=" ",)


vocales = "aeiouáéíóúAEIOUÁÉÍÓÚ"
consonantes = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ"
simbolos = " .,;"
cadena = str(input(""))
TraducirPseudoLatin(cadena,consonantes,vocales,simbolos)
```

Comment: El código no imprime nada.

Comment: Lo tengo que hacer sin los simbolos

Comment: Pero nose como poner una condicion para que se ejecute

Answer (score 0):

Esto es Python, no C. Hay formas más cortas y concisas de operar con listas:

```
def TraducirPseudoLatin(cadena, consonantes, vocales):
    latin = []
    for palabra in cadena.split():
        if palabra[-1] in consonantes:  # encontrar consonantes para reemplazar
            latin.append(palabra + "um")
        elif palabra[-1] in vocales:  # encontrar vocales para reemplazar
            latin.append(palabra[:-1] + "um")

    return ' '.join(latin)
```

Primero, si tengo una frase como "El pájaro canta hasta morir" la puedo dividir en una lista de palabras usando `split()`.

Esta lista la puede recorrer palabra usando un `for palabra in palabras:`.

Dada una palabra, su último caracter está en el indice `[-1]`, y puedo preguntar por él:

```
    if palabra[-1] in consonantes:  # encontrar consonantes para reemplazar
```

Si el caracter cumple, tomo la palabra, le concateno "um" y lo agrego a la lista de salida.

La lista de palabras traducidas las puedo reunificar en una frase usando `join()`.

#### Demo

```
def TraducirPseudoLatin(cadena, consonantes, vocales, simbolos):
    latin = []
    for palabra in cadena.split():
        if palabra[-1] in consonantes:  # encontrar consonantes para reemplazar
            latin.append(palabra + "um")
        elif palabra[-1] in vocales:  # encontrar vocales para reemplazar
            latin.append(palabra[:-1] + "um")

    return ' '.join(latin)


vocales = "aeiouáéíóúAEIOUÁÉÍÓÚ"
consonantes = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ"
simbolos = " .,;"
#cadena = str(input("Ingrese una frase"))
cadena = "El pájaro campana canta hasta morir"
print(TraducirPseudoLatin(cadena, consonantes, vocales, simbolos))
```

produce:

```
Elum pájarum campanum cantum hastum morirum

Process finished with exit code 0
```